# 3D reconstruction virtual environement for robot

Tags: 3d-reconstruction

I need advice about 3D scene reconstruction. I need to create the same for my robot in Ubuntu 20.04, ros2 galactic platform. As a newbie, could someone guide me in this regard? Is it possible to use NERF, and G-splatting in the available environment?